# Eclipse often does not suggest

Tags: java, eclipse, import, autosuggest

This is my Eclipse level:
Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520

Since I update to this from:
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200

I miss often suggestions for quick fixes.

For example:

```
private List<WayPoint> getUpdatedAndCondensedList(final List<WayPoint> tour) {
        List<WayPoint> tourBulletin = new ArrayList<>();
        return null;
    }
```

The Imports vor "List" and "ArrayList" are missing.
If right clicking to "List" in the signature line of the method, I'm suggestet to add import of "java.util.List". But if I do the same in the next, the instantiation line, this suggestion is missing. But it is not this easy, that the suggestion is always missing within the method. At least, I could not figure out, a consistent behaviour.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this reproducible in the [latest integration build](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)? If yes, make sure it has reported [here](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues) with a complete minimal reproducible example, best with a pull request with the fix. Please use Stack Overflow only for real questions, not as a bug tracker.